# addition of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

i have a table called temp_reading in this the following columns are there and is and consumption are primarykeys :

```
id consumption total
1  100
1  200
1  300
1  400
2  50
2  100
3  200
4  250
```

now i want to display total as

```
id   consumption  total
1    100          100
1    200          300
1    300          600
1    300          900
2    50           50
2    100          150
3    200          200
4    250          250
```

is it possible to display like the above 
i tried the following query

```
select id,consumption,sum(consumption) as total 
from temp_reading 
group by consumption;
```

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  id, 
        consumption,
         @accum:=@accum + a.runningTotal AS TOTAL
FROM 
    (  
      SELECT  id, 
              consumption, 
              SUM(consumption) AS runningTotal
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY id, consumption
      ORDER BY id, consumption
    ) a , (SELECT @accum := 0) s;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c11fd/9)